# Automating Hadoop batch processing commands

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, luigi

I am begginer in this domain so dont know exact terminology, sorry for that

**Question Base:** Want to automate the processing of batch layer

**Problem:** I am unable to understand that how people manage to run big hadoop command like

```
"hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0.jar \
    -mapper mapper.py \
    -reducer reducer.py \
    -input nfldata/stadiums \
    -output nfldata/pythonoutput \
    -file simple/mapper.py \
    -file simple/reducer.py"
```

every time they need to run a map reduce job,is there any way to automate the process like cron or something please let me know if there is any resource to learn about this so that we can schedule a hadoop command or something relating python or bash scripts

**What i have searched**: Luigi is something suggested([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801968/running-hadoop-jar-using-luigi-python)) to build jar or run command but there isn't any documentation or sample about it

**Note:** As i dont know java i havent searched and cant use option in java.

Comment: what is frequency you want to run the job? You can create a shell script and write this command into it and schedule it into the unix cron. That is the simplest approach. There are many scheduling tools available like Apache Oozie or Enterprise software like Tidal.

Comment: I want to run it through POST request on server or when new data is fed into hdfs, i mean there would be any approach to generate batch view atomatically or rule of thumb? or these command are run manually?

Comment: I am assuming you have setup of oozie server and client in your hadoop cluster. You can define you processing components in a oozie workflow xml, using a `map-reduce` action with `streaming` configuration. For running any workflow based on time (like daily) or data, you can use the oozie coordinator and schedule it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose between a Hadoop solution and a non-Hadoop solution.

**Hadoop Solution**

Hadoop has three main frameworks for this case:

- Oozie (http://oozie.apache.org/)
- Luigi (https://github.com/spotify/luigi
- Azkaban (https://azkaban.github.io/)

Each framework has its advantages and disadvantages. For example, Oozie is strongly XML based (what many people dislike) and you can write jobs that can be added to the oozie workflow engines. What people often like about Oozie is that they have a GUI to design workflows.

For details on Hadoop workflow solutions, google comparisons of these languages. There are many in-depts comparisions available

**Non-Hadoop-Solution**

Write your workflow code in any language (most likely a scripting language such as Python, Bash or Perl fits more into that use case than a compiled language). Add this application to a cron job and then run the application regularly.

Call all the commands (such as `hdfs dfs` or `hadoop jar`) with in the application. You are pretty flexible with catching exceptions or preparing statements with all the programming logic you need.

**HOW**

Working with Oozie would mean that you have a GUI to create your workflows by default, if you are using Hue. See also the screenshot. 
[image]

In your case, you can add your sample hadoop command in a GUI, you can specify in fields you mapper, reducer, etc. Then you can schedule your workflow.

[image]

As you can see, there are many oozie job templates, such as map reduce job. If you do not have a specific job template, you can implement your own Oozie Jobs in Java. Under the hood, Oozie stores the content in XML files, so you can edit your workflows and jobs also in XML.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2"
name="whitehouse-workflow">
<start to="transform_input"/>
<action name="transform_sample_pig">
  <pig>
    <job-tracker>${resourceManager}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <prepare>
      <delete path="pig_store"/>
    </prepare>
    <script>mypig.pig</script>
  </pig> 
  <ok to="end"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
</action>
<kill name="fail">
  <message>Job failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
  </message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

**scheduling/running**
Once you edit your workflow and design it, you have also the option of run or  schedule your workflow. The scheduling is a wizard that allows you define details such as frequency, input data or more advanced topics such as concurrency.

This shows another advantage of oozie compared to a script implementation. If you collaborate with users who occationally should be allowed to trigger workflows, it creates additional effort to integrate a script implementation into the GUI. With Oozie, it is just click and done.

[image: scheduling]

**Trade-Off**

As usual, there is no silver bullet of best tool that solves everything. With a Hadoop solution, you will have to learn a specific tool. It adds a learning curve to understand how Oozie, Luigi or Azkaban works.

This learning curve is not required, if you are already good with a programming language. Use a scripting languages and add your scripts to a scheduler such as cron. You have all the programming power to react on exceptions and customize your workflow. You give up comfort for a UI for programming power.

To sum it up, if you just have simple jobs to schedule then any Hadoop specific solution is enough. At a certain complexity and customization, an implementation with python adds flexibility at the cost of maintenance.

There is also a third option. There are a lot of professional ETL solutions on the market, such as Informatica, Talend or OSI.

Comment: Thanks for answering this, i have read about luigi and oozie but i am looking for "how" part of the answer , just a quick example as oozie like framework is complicated, i just want to set a task that as soon as data arrives i need to run hadoop statement

Comment: I added some infos to the how

Comment: thanks for such details upvoting  it so that it can be accepted as bounty by default. can you please add last thing that where in oozie we can put time or condition when will job be executed? i mean like every day at some time automatically?
again thanks alot for this

Comment: I added some scheduling information. You are pretty flexible how to schedule your oozie workflows. Most important thing is you can use HUE to administrate

Comment: @stephan thanks for details i will ping you if i have any query great details these are, have accepted it for bounty. you can still edit it if you beleive it needs any details for future users. thanks again